# How to fix "DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE" error in Chrome or other browsers?

Tags: window, firewall

I am trying to access the "Amazon web services console" but I am getting the below error "DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE" continuously.

I have tried to restart the router, and it worked but soon the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some setting change for DNS and it worked.
**1. Change DNS settings**

- Right-click on Start and pick Network Connections.
- Under Advanced network settings, pick Change adapter options.
- In the Network Connection window, right-click on your main connection
  (for example, Ethernet) and select Properties.
- Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and click Properties
  below.
- Click Use the following DNS server address and type in the following
  into the fields:
  **Preferred DNS server: 8.8.8.8**
  **Alternate DNS server: 8.8.8.9 Press OK.**